# ifmtarg testing a macro that is empty?

Tags: conditionals, programming, arguments, empty

The following code works as expected:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\checker}{m}{\@ifmtarg{#1}{empty}{not empty}}
\checker{}  % Prints "empty"
\checker{x} % Prints "not empty"
```

However, how to make it work when a potentially empty macro is provided as an argument:

```
\newcommand{\emptymacro}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\checker}{m}{\@ifmtarg{#1}{empty}{not empty}}
\checker{\emptymacro}  % Prints "not empty"
```

How to make it print `empty` by handling an empty macro as an empty argument?

Comment: `\newcommand\ifemptyoremptymacro[1]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi\fi}`

Comment: I'd use one of the macros from `etoolbox` instead.

Comment: How many expansion steps do you want? For instance, if `\a` expands to `\b` and `\b` expands to nothing, do you want that `\checker{\a}` returns empty or not? And what's such macros supposed to contain? For instance, if you want recursive expansion, so in the example `\checker{\a}` should return empty, you need to ensure that proper protected expansion is carried on.

Comment: @egreg I want full expansion. In the case you mention, it should return empty, and even with `\c`, `\d`, and so on recursively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `expl3` and recursive expansion.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checker}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_if_empty:eTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checker}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_if_empty:eTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\aaa}{\bbb}
\newcommand{\bbb}{\ccc}
\newcommand{\ccc}{}

\newcommand{\ddd}{\eee}
\newcommand{\eee}{e}

\begin{document}

\checker{}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{e}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\aaa}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\bbb}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\ccc}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\ddd}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\eee}{empty}{not empty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to consider “empty” also sequence of spaces, replace with

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checker}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:eTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checker}{mmm}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:eTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\aaa}{\bbb}
\newcommand{\bbb}{\ccc}
\newcommand{\ccc}{}

\newcommand{\ddd}{\eee}
\newcommand{\eee}{e}

\newcommand{\fff}{\space\space}

\begin{document}

\checker{}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{e}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\aaa}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\bbb}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\ccc}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\ddd}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\eee}{empty}{not empty}

\checker{\fff}{empty}{not empty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would that also work with empty string? For example if `\newcommand{\ccc}{}` is replaced by `\newcommand{\ccc}{  }`. In case it's not, how to also make it work with empty strings?

Comment: @Vincent A macro expanding to a space is not empty. You didn't ask for “empty or consisting only of spaces”. Anyway, I added the method: just replace `_empty` with `_blank`.

Comment: Gosh. That almost (but not quite) inspires me to learn some expl3. There is a web page that says it "expands like a boss". Now I know what that means.